# Join Domain and Dos App

Tags: domain-server, ms-dos

First off, yes I have read all the related topics and those fixes are either out of date or don't work.

I am running 12.04 and I would like to add it to the Windows 2008 Server network. After I get that done I would like to mount the `F:\` drive of the server somewhere on my Linux machine where it can be identified as drive `F:\` by Wine or Dosemu.

If I can achieve all of that, I need to find out how to run a MS-Dos 16-bit Point-of-sales Graphic program in Ubuntu.

whether that be through Wine, Dosemu, or DosBox, it does not matter, it just has to be able to read and write to the servers `F:\` drive, operate the DOS app, and support LPt1 (I think) for printing receipts and loading tickets.

I am a decently knowledgeable Windows tech, at least thats what my job description says. But this is my first encounter with Linux in a work environment, it could prove to very experience changing if I can just prove it as a practical theory and a reasonable solution, and get it to work.

The first step is to get it joined to the domain. I have likewise-open CLI and GUI versions, samba, and GADMIN-SAMBA installed in attempts to get any of them to work.

Any help in any area is greatly appreciated, especially with the domain joining since it is the first step and what I thought would be the easiest step.

Comment: I fail to see why you would prefer a POS in msdos in ubuntu to interact with a windows server. Too much microsoft products involved in my opinion. Have you tried other POS programs?  http://www.foodservice.com/blogs/show.cfm?contentid=13425&title=10%20Popular%20Free%20Open%20source%20POS

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to join the domain to be able to access its resources as long as you specify what realm(domain) you are authenticating from/ to.
That is the case both in Linux and windows. So skip it.

here is an example of how to mount a network folder on a windows domain.

```
sudo mkdir /media/servershare
sudo mount -t smbfs -o username=yourusername,workgroup=yourdomainame,users //DnsNameOfServer/sharename /media/servershare
```

I believe dosbox currently doesen't support parallel port mapping.

Wine is used for Windows applications and you are talking about a dos application so it's not going to work either.

This leaves you with running either dosemu or Virtualbox.
I would start with Virtualbox since it has a nice GUI and easy options for mapping hardware devices and folders to it's guest.